# Does jQuery have a collect method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
  var selected = new Array();
        $(".client_associates_users input:checked").each(function(index) {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        });
```

and it works great but i was wondering if jQuery had a collect so i would not have to create an array and push to it.

I basically want all the values of the checked input fields

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `$.fn.map` http://api.jquery.com/map/ or `$.map` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

```
var $checkboxes = $(".client_associates_users input:checked"),
    selected = $checkboxes.map(function(i){
        return $checkboxes.eq(i).val();
    }).get();
```

or this for `$.map` (I prefer this one)

```
var $checkboxes = $(".client_associates_users input:checked"),
    selected = $.map($checkboxes, function(el,i){
        return $checkboxes.eq(i).val();
    });
```

**Update**
No longer recreates a jQuery object on each iteration.

Comment: I'll give it a +1 as soon as you don't re-create jQuery objects in every iteration.

Comment: @jAndy -- Removed my old comment as it had a bad typo. It basically compared `.value` to `.val()` which isn't really relevant to what you were saying. As you said, there's no reason to re-create the jQuery object on each iteration. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery offers the `.map()` method,

```
var selected = $(".client_associates_users input:checked").map(function(index) {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

This method will create a new array out of whatever data you `return` from within the callback. Be aware that you need to call `.get()` at the end to get a real array.

Ref.: [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: ... so you'll probably want to use it, instead of `each` =)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object `$(".client_associates_users input:checked")` is an array so you should just be able to access those values if you append a `.val()` to the end of that selector.

Comment: @jasonmerino -- `.val()` and other getter methods in jQuery always return the value from the first selected element rather than all selected elements.

Comment: Right, I should have specified to use `.eq(i).val()` or something of that nature...